# Change URL After Action is Hit MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, url, url-routing

I want to change:

```
www.testurl.com/sports/blog/1
```

Where sports is my area, blog is my action and 1 is an ID of a blog post, to:

```
www.testurl.com/sports/blog/test-title-of-blog
```

Where blog is still my action but the id is not shown, but instead the title/permalink of the blog is.

Here is my AreaRegistration for this action:

```
context.MapRoute(
                "sports",
                "sports/{action}/{content}",
                new { area = "Sports", controller = "Sports", action = "", content = "" });
```

Here is my action at the moment:

```
[HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Blog(string content)
    {
            int contentId;
            if (Int32.TryParse(content, out contentId))
            {
                model = service.GetBlogById(contentId);
            }
            else
            {
                model = service.GetBlogByTitle(content);
            }

            //Change URL to be: www.testurl.com/sports/blog/ + model.SEOFriendlyTitle
            return View(model);            
    }
```

Users are able to search via the ID of the blog, but also by the title of it, but I only want the title to appear in the url bar, never the id.

I cannot do this via Redirect rules due to the continuing maintenance that would cause.

1. **Is the controller the right place to do this?**  -Remember I may not have my title until after I retrieve it from the database using the ID
2. **How would I go about changing the URL to display the title vs. the ID?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you should do is return a RedirectResult to the new Url if the ID is numeric and is a valid contentId :

```
            int contentId;
            if (Int32.TryParse(content, out contentId))
            {
                model = service.GetBlogById(contentId);
                if(model != null)
                {
                    return RedirectResult(/*url using the title*/);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                model = service.GetBlogByTitle(content);
            }

            //Change URL to be: www.testurl.com/sports/blog/ + model.SEOFriendlyTitle
            return View(model);
```

Of course, that will cause another round trip to the server but I can see a way to change the browser URL without a page redirect. You should also make sure that all published urls on your site are using the title instead of Id.

I hope it will help.

Comment: This is exactly what I did.  I too thought of the second trip to the db and server, but can avoid the db call by passing the object in tempData and checking to see if that exists.  This is an instance that would be very edge case and all of the url's on the site would be by page title... I just wanted to be able to support an ID if given instead of the title.  This is the accepted answer because it solves the problem I had (though maybe causing others in its place :P )

Answer (score 0):

I suggest giving this a quick read.

http://www.dominicpettifer.co.uk/Blog/34/asp-net-mvc-and-clean-seo-friendly-urls

If you are really can't have the ID in Url and don't want to do redirects then I think storing Url as Slugs in the database is the only other option.

****Some points if you are going to do this.****

1. Add a Unique Constraint to the column at the Database Level to avoid duplicates.
2. Create a Database Index on this column to speed up you reads.

So with this Url

```
www.testurl.com/sports/blog/test-title-of-blog
```

This is your unique slug that you will query the database for instead of an ID

```
test-title-of-blog
```

Comment: Good article, and will most likely will update to use ID as well, but the MUST have is the title.  I guess what I was trying to get at is if there was some MVC Class I could use to edit the url from the action.