# Change Action Parameter but keep URL same

Tags: c#, url, parameter-passing, actionresult

So I have a C# .NET project.
On certain pages I need to change a parameter passed through the ActionResult but still keep the original URL.

In order to change the parameter to the one I needed, I changed the variable through the ActionContext. But this then changes the URL to the parameter - which is expected but not wanted.

```
public class CustomController : Controller {
    protected override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext) {
        if (isReplaceType) {
            // replace action parameter to needed one
            filterContext.ActionParameters["variable1"] = replacedVariable;

            // Fake URL code here ??? ----------------
        }
        base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
    }
}
```

I need to change **site.com/replacedVariable** to **site.com/originalVariable** in the user's browser URL bar.

How can I do this?

---

EDIT: Route looks like this in Global.asax

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "HomeDefault",
    url: "{variable1}/{action}",
    defaults: new { controller = "home", action = "index" },
    namespaces: new string[] { "Project.Controllers" }
);
```

Comment: On the server side you would send a response that redirects the browser to the desired URL.

Comment: *site.com/replacedVariable* and *site.com/originalVariable* are different. So which is it? Did you want to change from one to the other, or did you want to keep the URL the same?

Comment: It seems like you're probably doing something a bit strange with your routing. Can you give a complete description of the problem, in particular what the variables are for, and the problem you're trying to solve, so that we can answer the question better? Thanks.

Comment: @JonathanWood site.com/originalVariable and site.com/replacedVariable will go to the same page and do the same actions. Just I need it to look like site.com/originalVariable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading through this question: [Change URL After Action is Hit MVC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13569588/change-url-after-action-is-hit-mvc)
It suggests that the only way to change the URL is to *redirect the page* - meaning changing an action variable was not the reason why the URL changed to the new variable.

I found that the page redirected in certain cases and this is why it changed. Hence, in order to fix it, I have overridden the Redirect function and replaced the new variable with the old value in the URL.

```
public class CustomController : Controller {
    protected override RedirectResult Redirect(string url) {
        if (Session["replacedVariable"] == null) {
            return base.Redirect(url);
        }

        string replaceUrl = url.Replace("/" + Session["replacedVariable"], "/originalVariable");
        return base.Redirect(replaceUrl);
    }
}
```